# ZedGraph, record position when mousedown x-axis, C#

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I'm using ZedGraph to plot some line graphs in C#.
What I'm trying to do is record the on screen x axis positions when you zoom in and out with the mouse as I want to work out the max and min values that are displayed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question very well, but you can get the screen coordinates of the mouse location, then call [ReverseTransform](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/M_ZedGraph_GraphPane_ReverseTransform_1.htm) to get the location in the graph.